# Android support library SearchView xml attributes queryHint and iconifiedByDefault not working

Tags: android, searchview

I have the following SearchView in a layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:queryHint="@string/search"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"

     />
```

However when i run my application no hint appears and the searchview is iconified, in code it works my question is is this a bug on the supportlibrary ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are missing required **namespace**. Replace `[yourapp]` with your app name in XML layout. Use this namespace for SearchView properties. This approach is necessary if you use views from support library. Btw. you must do the same with [menu for AppCompat action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored/20119706#17914095).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:[yourapp]="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_address_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/global_bg_front"
        android:textSize="@dimen/global_text_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/global_text_primary"
        [yourapp]:queryHint="@string/fragment_address_search_hint"
        [yourapp]:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also setup your SearchView programmatically. See my [template on GitHub](https://github.com/petrnohejl/Android-Templates-And-Utilities/tree/master/Src-ActionBar-Search).

```
private void setupSearchView(SearchView searchView)
{
    // search hint
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.fragment_address_search_hint));

    // background
    View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.searchview_bg);

    // icon
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.searchview_icon);

    // clear button
    ImageView searchClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.searchview_clear);

    // text color
    AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.global_text_primary));
    searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.global_text_secondary));
}
```

Comment: Thanks i was aware how that worked for AppCompact but was unaware that it was the same for the support library

Comment: can you help me, how to make searchIcon GONE and do not use space before hint ?

Comment: AndrewS: Try to use AutoCompleteTextView instead of SearchView.