# Changing SearchView Search Icon Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to change the search icon in a SearchBarRenderer Android custom renderer

and that's what I tried

```
 Control.Iconified = false;
 Control.SetIconifiedByDefault(false);

 var searchView = Control.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.search_button);
 var searchicon = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.search);
 searchView.SetImageDrawable(searchicon);
```

However, searchIcon is always null

When I looped through the children of SearchView I found and image view with ID  **16909229** but setting the image drawable of that didn't change the search icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to change the search icon in a SearchBarRenderer Android custom renderer

Modify your code like this:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchBar), typeof(MySearchBarRenderer))]
namespace yourprjectnamespace
{
    public class MySearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        public MySearchBarRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var searchView = Control;

                int searchViewCloseButtonId = Control.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);

                var closeIcon = searchView.FindViewById(searchViewCloseButtonId);
                (closeIcon as ImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.icon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SnUP.png).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` you can try to set it like this:

```
var searchIcon = (ImageView) searchView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_mag_icon);
searchIcon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.my_custom_search_icon);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362491/6248510 it's not the same question but it is related to it and in the answer it is included a way to set it

Comment: that might work for Android it wont work for xamarin

Comment: does it throw any error? Adapted the code for Xamarin

Comment: in fact it isn't, the Resource.Id is different. You wrote `Resource.Id.search_button` while I `Resource.Id.search_mag_icon` instead