# How can I change the colors of the icon and underline of the SearchBar using AppThemColor?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Currently, I'm using these AppThemeColors.

```xml
<AppThemeColor x:Key="PrimaryColor"
               Light="Teal"
               Dark="Indigo"/>

<AppThemeColor x:Key="SecondaryColor"
               Light="White"
               Dark="Black"/>
```

How can I change the color of the SearchBar icon and underline using these AppThemeColors?

Comment: We need to use Custom Renderer to customize the search bar . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368039/changing-searchview-search-icon-xamarin-android .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue on iOS 13 onwards in the search bar for iOS. According to the [issue filed in Xamarin's GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8041), you can use a [PlatformEffect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction) to implement that:

```
public class SearchBarBackgroundEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    public SearchBarBackgroundEffect()
    {
    }

    private UIKit.UISearchBar NativeSearchBar => (UIKit.UISearchBar)Control;
    private SearchBar XamarinSearchBar => (SearchBar)Element;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (UIKit.UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            NativeSearchBar.SearchTextField.BackgroundColor = XamarinSearchBar.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
    }
    protected override void OnDetached()
    {

    }
}
```