# ActionBar items appear always in Overflow Menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to add actions item in action bar, but items always are adding into the overflow list even there is lot of room. Any suggestion to resolve this ??

[image]

This should be like this

[image]

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actionbardemo.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.actionbardemo.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: if there is not enough space it appears in the overflow menu. its seems there is enough space but its not

Comment: @Raghunandan that why I asked question here

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: @Raghunandan I have read that, I could not trace my problem

Comment: there is no space hence it does not appear to you it looks like there is enough space but its not

Comment: @Williams Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored

Comment: Are you sure that there is space for "Refresh" text ? Try with a single dummy letter. I think it is due to unavailability of Room for the text.

Comment: @Williams the other thing is your min sdk is 8. so you need `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" ` and this `yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" `

Comment: I tried an example with the showAs=ifRoom and all the items gets displayed fine in the action bar. Not sure why it is causing an issue for you. The program is same as yours with the versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My app is using the Support Library for compatibility on versions as low as Android 2.2 so I have to define my  own XML namespace and use that namespace as the attribute prefix

Solution was this, I was writing this `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` but I should have `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_refresh" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

Comment: that is bcoz your min sdk is 8 and you use AppCompat to support actionbar below api level 11. do mention the reason in your post

Answer (score 5):

in menu xml file you need to add yourapp:showAsAction="always" like below.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/Option"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:title="Option"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/Save"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
    android:title="Save"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: which actionbar you using meance v4 or appcompact

Comment: @PankajAndroid 'always' is not recommended 'ifroom' is better let the OS decide.

Comment: @ZohraKhan i had used appcomct it working fine. but i had add only two item.

Comment: @PankajAndroid 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'

Comment: @Williams then i thing it should work becuse same thing i had face and with this showAsAction it's work.. what issue u face in showAsAction?

Comment: Yes, seems helpful +1

Comment: @AndroGeek Solution was this, I was writing this android:showAsAction="ifRoom" but I should have app:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Answer (score 4):

As per the [document](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on versions as low as 
Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not available from the android: namespace. Instead this attribute is provided by the Support Library and you must define your own XML namespace and use that namespace as the attribute prefix. (A custom XML namespace should be based on your app name, but it can be any name you want and is only accessible within the scope of the file in which you declare it.) For example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_search" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show all items always in actionbar then make your menu xml file like below:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_search" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: I tried this also but still same issue, there is already room there No need of using always all time

Comment: that means there is no space then

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue before you should try this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_search" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score -4):

Try with  `android:showAsAction="always"` for the items in the menu.

Comment: @AndroGeek its a short answer that doesn't explain why it *should* work or what basis it has, its just a 'try' *and* apparently it didn't work.