# Why the menu items appear on the optionsMenu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

Despite there are some icons associated with certain action and have no enough space in the `Actionbar`, they appear in the `optionsMenu` instead of appearing in the `overflow` icon.

I am inflating the `actionBar` with five icons each one has a specific functionality "Please refer to the XML file below", the items which have the `android:showAsAction=never`
I expect them to implicitly reside inside the `overflow` icon on the `actionBar`, but when I run the App, any item with the property `android:showAsAction=never` instead it appears in the `optionsMenu`. Why that happens? and I hope i explained the problem clearly.

***Update***:

Simply, I want, if there is no space for the icon to be placed on the `ActionBar`, They should be placed inside the `overflow` icon as shown in the image " the icon with three vertical dots over each other".

**To Note**:

I am using Galaxy Note3

[image]

> Why my question is marked as a duplicate. The question suggested as a duplicate is different than mine? Please review the question again.

***Java_Code***:

```
public class ActionBarActivityTest00 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_activity_test00);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_activity_test00, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

***XML***:

```
<menu 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.actionbaractivitytest.ActionBarActivityTest00" >

<!-- Search / will display always -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Location Found -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
      android:title="action_location_found"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Refresh -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:title="action_refresh"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Help -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:title="action_help"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>

<!-- Check updates -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:title="action_check_updates"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBar items appear always in Overflow Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829131/actionbar-items-appear-always-in-overflow-menu)

Comment: @SimplePlan thank you, I have just tried your suggestion ut unfortunately, once there is an icons overflow on the actionbar, the overplus icons is replaced automatically on the optionsmenu

Comment: Your code is working fine at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Add below property in showasaction=never All menu items

```
android:orderInCategory="2"
```

thats it..it will shown in overflow men..
Changes My Sample Code for your scenario and it works fine in my app

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.demo.MainActivity" >

 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings1"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings5"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: i tried you answer, unfortunately, if there is no space for the icon to e placed on the actionbar they will e placed in the optionmenus and not inside the overflow icon as the image shows

Comment: I am testing my app on galaxy note3. do you think the version of the device might matter?

Comment: have you add appCompact lib?

Comment: and one more thing Replace Activity with ActionBarActivity in your mainActivity class.then check....

Comment: when i right click on the project->properties->Android: there is `appcompat-V7` is checked with green sign. is it what you mean?

Comment: I replaced Activity with ActionBarActivity and the result is: all the item are placed inside the options manue and nn of the on the actionbar any mmore? "befuddling"

Comment: would u please tell me which file i should download?

Comment: whole project download and import.

Comment: I actually, trie your updated answer but unfortunately it i not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.fafad.MainActivity" >

  <!-- Search / will display always -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="action_search"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Location Found -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
      android:title="action_location_found"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Refresh -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:orderInCategory="3"
      android:title="action_refresh"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Help -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:orderInCategory="4"
      android:title="action_help"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>

<!-- Check updates -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:orderInCategory="5"
      android:title="action_check_updates"
      app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```