# How to create an activity with options in ActionBar and OptionsMenu together?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-optionsmenu, options-menu

In the same activity, I want to place some options in the `optionsMenu` and some on the `ActionBarActivity`. Should I create a separate `xml` file for the options to be placed in the `optionsMenu` and another `xml` file for those I want to place them on the `ActionBar`?

OR I have to create a single `xml` file for both? And in either cases, what will distinguish the options to be placed on the `ActionBar` than the others to be in the `optionsmenu`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [action bar and its overflow area](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) (i.e. the "three dots")?

You need to create a single xml file with all the menu options, and then control this with the `android:showAsAction` attribute on each one. For example, if you set `ifRoom`  then it will be included in the action bar (provided there is enough space), while `never` will put the item in the overflow menu.

See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

Comment: thank you. No, i do not mean `actionbar` and the rest of the options to reside inside the `overflow icon`. i mean some of the options to appear on the `actionbar` and some options in the `options menu` the menu that appear when you press the options button "the button on the lower left side of your device.

Comment: would you please, if you do not mind, take a look at that questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286112/why-the-menu-items-appear-on-the-optionsmenu

Comment: @Elpharaoh It's the same. On devices with a physical menu button, the overflow menu is what is shown when you press it.