# Android show menu item as action in Activity extends FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

If you want to show a menu item in action bar, the activity MUST extends `ActionBarActivity` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/).

I have an activity which extends `FragmentActivity`. Actually I have to extend `FragmentActivity` because I'm using Tabs in my Application.

So my question is, how can I **show a menu item as action bar** and also use **Tabs** in my activity?!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use ActionBarActivity it is child of FragmentActivity

Comment: Oh thank you. I guess it was a stupid question.