# Xamarin ActionBar button items hidden

Tags: c#, android, android-actionbar, xamarin

I want my action bar to show items. All three of the items are hidden in the triple dot icon even though I have `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` for all three items. There is certainly enough room, yet they aren't showing. How can I make them show?

MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //...
    this.ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //...
}

//...

public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    return true;
}
```

MyFragment.cs (inherits Fragment)

```
public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    HasOptionsMenu = true;
}

//...

public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionbar_search, menu);
}
```

actionbar_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

  <item android:id="@+id/addnew"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_new"
    android:title="Add New"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/searcher"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

  <item android:id="@+id/refresher"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Also, the main activity is a Navigation Drawer that uses `Fragments` for the content. It works similarly to this: http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/NavigationDrawer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `app:showAsAction="always"`

See this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored) as well.

Comment: The answer you linked was helpful. I had to change `android` to `app`.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out.