# Error : should use android:showAsAction when not using support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-support-library

I'm using app compact support library v7 for providing support of lollipop in my app. I was able to make it work perfectly. When my actionbar not showing menu items as icon.

I have followed   [this link](http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/) to make it work  .
Following is my **menu.xml** :

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item
    android:id="@+id/contact_add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_btn_add_contact"
    android:title="@string/add" 
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/contact_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_btn_add_contact"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/delete"/>
</menu>
```

Still I am getting following error : `should use android:showAsAction when not using appcompat library`

What am I doing wrong ???

Comment: and i think your parent is Activity class.

Comment: @TusharPandey: I had tried using `ifRoom` still issue was there. and i'm using this menu in fragment but parent of that activity is extending `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: or may be you are using samsung device where, overflow will be displayed with menu button in device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in following manner :

Go to `Build Path/Configure Build Path` and on the `Order and Export` tab,

```
check the support jars and uncheck Android Dependencies.
```

Do this for support library `android-support-v7-appcompat` also. Then just `clean` your project and error is solved.

[Here](http://right-handed-monkey.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-run-android-support-library.html) is the link from where I get this.

Answer (score 8):

Update your Menu Bar with this code

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ><item
android:id="@+id/contact_add"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_btn_add_contact"
android:title="@string/add" 
app:showAsAction="always"/><item
android:id="@+id/contact_delete"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_btn_add_contact"
app:showAsAction="never"
android:title="@string/delete"/></menu>
```

You are getting the error because you are using

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

You are supposed to write it as

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```