# Actionbar buttons ignored by inflater

Tags: android

Im using a custom actionbar theme (really just changed color) and disabling home icon (in main activity). I have 2 menu items that I want inflated and 'always' on the action bar. When i run the app they are both pushed into overflow.

I referred to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored) and went the route of using a custom namespace because Support v7 and still the same results. I was wondering if me using a custom actionbar theme is having anything to do with it?

here is my main_activity_actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:Velo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/add_ride"
        android:title="@string/add_ride"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        Velo:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        Velo:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

and here is the usual boilerplate inflater

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

not sure if u guys wanna see anything else, but let me know.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** : It's weird. I can use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and get an error on it (red line underneath) and just ignore it and run and it works how I want, but if I use the namespace `appname:showAsAction="ifRoom"` it wont work. I mean I would like to do it the proper way, but whats the harm in ignoring this error?

Comment: I would try with a lowercase letter, just to be 100% sure.

Comment: Does giving **android:orderInCategory="int"** works?

Comment: Try also returning `true` instead of `super.`.

Comment: Try this android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Comment: Make sure you're using `ActionBarActivity`, and a v7 theme.

Comment: Elaborate please. someone else said that then deleted their response, so im not too sure what you guys mean

Comment: Elaborate what? What activity class are you extending?

Comment: what is a v7 theme? im using a custom one.

Comment: What activity class are you extending?

Comment: my MainActivity class extends fragment activity for other purposes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FragmentActivity`, then you are not using [AppCompat v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat), which provides a consistent ActionBar from API 7 and up. You can continue to use `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and use `FragmentActivity`, but your menu items will only show up in the Action Bar on API 11 or higher devices (which is when the ActionBar became a built in part of Android).

The other approach is to switch to using AppCompat (a [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) about the newest revision, v21, may be helpful to read over) and use its `ActionBarActivity`. This would give you a consistent action bar experience before API 11, API 11-20, and API 21 (as API 21 changes quite a bit on how the Action Bar works).

Answer (score 0):

From the `FragmentActivity` docs:

> Note: If you want to implement an activity that includes an action
>   bar, you should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a
>   subclass of this one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level
>   7 and higher.

Since you want your activity to have an ActionBar and you're saying you want v7 support, extend `ActionBarActivity`. Then you'll need to use `AppCompat` theme.

If you want to use a base theme other than `AppCompat`, you'll have to extend `Activity` and change your minSdk to 11 or higher.

Basically to support API 7 you need to stick to the `AppCompat` theme from the support package.

Comment: okay, so if I change my `extends FragmentActivity` to `extends ActionBarActivity` and then in my themes.xml I change the parent to Theme.Appcompat.... then I should be good (is the gist of what your saying?)

Comment: @erp Correct but it's styles not themes (should be). If you choose to go with the ActionBarActivity, then use the custom namespace, else if Activity then use `android`.