# Having an issue with Android ActionBar menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hello there guys,

I'm new to Android, I tried to add a Menu to my Android application something like this : [image: ActionBar]

The problem is that i'm not getting the menu on the action bar, I'm getting it down without icon.

Here is my code :

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
     switch (item.getItemId())
     {
     case R.id.chat:
        // Single menu item is selected do something
        // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Chat is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return true;


     default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

}

and here is the xml file :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/chat"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
      android:title="action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
```

Here is a screenshot of the application as you can see the menu is DOWN and without icon :

[image]

Manifest :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.menu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You can try android:showAsAction="always".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it shows the Menu down always

Comment: Now I am unable to understand your problem

Comment: Are you on a device/emulator with hardware menu buttons?

Comment: Are you using the v7 appCompat library? If so, see [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored).

Comment: @amram99 Yes v7 appCompat library  I'm on Device

Comment: Please, post also your manifest

Comment: You need to namespace your showAsAction attribute. See the accepted answer on the previous question that I shared.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it doesn't work, but I'm not sure if I really understood what I should modify ! can you make it clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `android:showAsAction` in your menu XML file from `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to `android:showAsAction="always"`. That should work.

**Update**

Change `inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);` to `inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` and use the `main.xml` file in the menu folder instead of the `menu.xml` file in your `layout` folder.

**Update 2**

Since you mentioned in your comment that you are using the appcompat library, you should modify your `main.xml` file in your `menu` folder as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->

<item android:id="@+id/chat"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
      android:title="action_search"
      compat:showAsAction="always" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->

</menu>
```

Comment: What is the name of your menu file?

Comment: the name of the time is menu.xml

Comment: Where did you save it? In the menu folder or in the layout folder?

Comment: When your activity is created, the menu XML document is also automatically created. So confirm that an XML file exists in the menu folder with the same name as your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `menu` to the menu folder and do it like:

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

Comment: Are you using Activity or ActionBarActivity?