# Why does android need showAsAction="always" to be prefixed with an alias?

Tags: android

I just started my journey on Android Development and there's one thing that is confusing me.

When creating menu items why do we need to specify an alias for  properties when android studio's autocomplete suggests the use of android:showAsAction="value"?

when using android:showAsAction the property is ignored. If i replace it for anything else it works. Why?

Related
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914095/1084568

Comment: It's not `anything else`. It's the namespace you defined earlier: `xmlns:[yourapp]="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. Nothing stops you defining `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: by define the namespace you mean use this: xmlns:doo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" /////// where doo is my namespace?

Comment: **Yes**, exactly. `xmlns = XML NameSpace`

Comment: After all it was simple and i was complicating. From the linked post, the yellow rectangle cites a reference from the documentation, where it says that `android: ` namespace  is not able to provide access to the property if the we pretend to support older android versions such as 2.1. Thanks for the clarification @DerGolem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the native action bar, you use `android:showAsAction`. Any time you see `android:` as a prefix, you know that it is an attribute defined by the Android framework.

If you are using the `appcompat-v7` backport of the action bar, that comes from a library (`appcompat-v7`). Libraries cannot invent new `android:` attributes. Instead, for library-defined attributes, you use a new namespace (e.g., `app:`) tied to a `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` URL.

> it says that android: namespace is not able to provide access to the property if the we pretend to support older android versions such as 2.1

Correct. In this case, while `android:showAsAction` was added to the framework in Android 3.0, part of the goal of `appcompat-v7` is to support back to Android 2.1. While Google has a time machine, they have not been using it to "retcon" Android and add in attributes that formerly did not exist.

<sub>(though, if they did, we wouldn't know about it, as our past would have been altered to have those attributes, unless we somehow have an existence outside the normal space-time continuum, which frequently seems to involve wearing a cape)</sub>

So, `appcompat-v7` can use attributes like `android:icon`, which existed from Android 1.0, but cannot support an `android:showAsAction` prior to Android 3.0. Hence, they have their own attribute.

Comment: Superb, this gives me even more insight on how things are structured. I wasn't aware that showAsAction had been introduced since v3.0.