# how to force ActionBar to display ALL items

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

i tried some sugestions here but no one worked,

this is the problem, the arrow indicate where i want them

the action bar is displaying just 2 icons
[image]

and the other are in the 3 dots menu

[image]

My custom_menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/btnBold"
    android:icon="@drawable/text_bold"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
    android:title="Teste1">
</item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnItalic"
        android:icon="@drawable/text_italic"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
        android:title="teste2">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnUnderline"
        android:icon="@drawable/text_underline"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
        android:title="teste3">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnStrike"
        android:icon="@drawable/text_strike"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
        android:title="teste2">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnForeground"
        android:icon="@drawable/text_foreground"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
        android:title="teste2">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btnBackground"
        android:icon="@drawable/text_background"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked"
        android:title="teste2">
    </item>

</menu>
```

and the code at the MainActivity

```
private ActionMode mActionMode = null;

    @Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        if (mActionMode == null) {
            mActionMode = mode;
            Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
            // Remove the default menu items (select all, copy, paste, search)
            menu.clear();

            // If you want to keep any of the defaults,
            // remove the items you don't want individually:
            // menu.removeItem(android.R.id.[id_of_item_to_remove])

            // Inflate your own menu items
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_custom_menu, menu);
        }

        super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    }

    // This method is what you should set as your item's onClick
    // <item android:onClick="onContextualMenuItemClicked" />
    public void onContextualMenuItemClicked(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.btnBold:
                // do some stuff
                break;
            case R.id.btnItalic:
                // do some different stuff
                break;
            default:
                // ...
                break;
        }

        // This will likely always be true, but check it anyway, just in case
        if (mActionMode != null) {
            //mActionMode.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
        super.onActionModeFinished(mode);
    }
```

Comment: and whats going to happen when they dont all fit on the screen?

Comment: in this case its ok to shrink, but it has a lot of space in the left, why hide?

Comment: the actionbar does not shrink items, what you want to do is not going to work

Comment: shrink was just way to say, so i have to change my approach =/, you know how to make a popup dialog appaer above the selected item? i mean, like when you have a EditText/TExtview and select text, a kind of bublle appear, maybe this can fit my needs (sorry this question here)

Comment: Hi @user2582318, did you figure a way out?

Comment: @Luccas, its impossible, you cant show all items, i changed it to a normal relativelayout and i show it when i need! You can create a toolbar and add a lot of buttons and show, but in the actionbar you cant, it automatically reduce and display one or two, you can just choose which ONE you want to display first

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the answer of this question?

[Android 4.3 menu item showAsAction="always" ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored)

Basically, what he said was that you must be missing the namespace. 
The proper way to do this would be:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:[yourapp]="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_add_size"
    android:title="@string/menu_add_item"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    [yourapp]:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
</menu>
```

I had this problem and solved it by changing the specific namespace. Hope you can fix by doing this too.