# Action bar menu item is duplicating in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Menu item showing on both never and always states

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:apptivo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">    
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_white"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="@string/create_string"
        apptivo:showAsAction="always" />    
</menu>
```

Comment: what you want finally ?

Comment: I want menu item in always state.  Don't want in both states

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored

Answer (score 0):

check if your menu is being created more than once, if have Activity or fragment that creates the menu, and class that it extend is creating the same menu you would have this. more over if you are creating the menu in the fragment and the fragment is being add more than once you would see this