# ActionBar icon not displaying with my icon

Tags: android, android-menu

here deleted setting action bar and inserted my icon;while compile it shows default dropdown setting;i need to replace it with my icon and should be clickable.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Changing name space from android to app ,if you are using the support libs can help.

Comment: When you click it,did it show your icon

Comment: can you explain me clearly!

Comment: yes,i want remove the setting icon and replace my icon with clickable on right side

Comment: Replace `android:showAsAction="always"` with `app:showAsAction="always"`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sanjeet Ajnabee explains, try using `android:showAsAction="always"` you should use `app:showAsAction="always"` and add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your `menu` tag. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914017/android-4-3-menu-item-showasaction-always-ignored)

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

tools:context="com.example.loadimage.MainActivity" >


<item

    android:id="@+id/icon_id"

    android:orderInCategory="100"

    android:icon="@drawable/youricon"

    android:title="@string/action_settings"

    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```