# "ifRoom" does not work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, menu

This is menu I've created:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="ninja.majewski.timetableapp.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_class_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

And this is how it looks like in the emuator which is wrong because title does not fit in the toolbar:

[image]

Wchen I launch the app on my phone it appears to work right:

[image]

But when I change the title it appears wrong:

[image]

My problem is that icons are not showing on the last screen and they appear on the first screen while they should be hidden.

How can I fix that?

Comment: what is your actual problem

Comment: if room not only depends on the title text length but also on the px size of the icons specified in the menu

Comment: My problem is that icons are not showing on the last screen and they appear on the first screen while they should be hidden

Comment: Did you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17914172/4860513 Maybe, you should replace app:showAsAction by [appName]:showAsAction

Comment: Still not working right :/ Nothing changed

Comment: Ok. I have some errors also. In my case, I replaced by android:showAsAction.. Android studio will say that is wrong but you can build normally... That worked for me... At least, in the devices and Android Versions that I tested....

Comment: I've changed it to this: `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` but now they are all hidden :/ Even if I change this to `always`