# How to remove action menu in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I trying to create a simple app with the material dark theme. When I select the Material Dark theme, the title bar shows up on the UI with the name of the app. Along with it, there are three vertical dots which, when clicked on, show a popup menu. I have tried all the themes available but I cannot remove that action menu. If i select NoActionBar, it removes the title as well as the actions menu. I want it to remove just the actions menu, but keep the Title bar. How is this possible ?

Comment: do you mean `overflow menu` ?

Comment: whats the difference ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable/hide three-dot indicator(Option menu indicator) on ICS handsets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206530/how-to-disable-hide-three-dot-indicatoroption-menu-indicator-on-ics-handsets)

Comment: @sufiyan It's not a duplicate of that question - OP seems to be referring to the overflow menu in the Action Bar, not the additional menu button on software navigation devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only show that popup menu if you have menu items in that activity.

In Android Studio, you can use the shortcut `cmd-shift-o` (OSX) or `ctrl-shift-n` (Win/Linux) to use the open project file tool. Search for "menu", then delete the file (it will be an XML file in `res/menu`) if you don't need it.

In your Activity, search for references to the now-deleted menu, and remove them.