# Hide 3-dot menu item when the Navigationbar appears

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation

I want to hide the three-dot menu item when the navigationbar appears.
I found some nice topics how to hide the three-dot menu item:
[How to disable/hide three-dot indicator(Option menu indicator) on ICS handsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206530/how-to-disable-hide-three-dot-indicatoroption-menu-indicator-on-ics-handsets)
[How do I hide a menu item in the actionbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar)
But I can not find a solution for my problem. I hope for some help. :)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    infoDialogFragment.aboutMenuItem(this);
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}


private void setNavigationDrawer() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {


    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Delete `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`. The settings menu will disappear.

Comment: but it should disappear when the navigationbar appears.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of this codes from your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    infoDialogFragment.aboutMenuItem(this);
    return false;
}
```